# DAO Function to insert data from one table to another

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, dao

I'm trying to write a function that inserts data from one table to another at the same way from the conventional insert, and I did something like this:

```
public class MySQLPriorityDAO implements PriorityDAO {

    final String INSERTFROM = "INSERT INTO priorities (callId, priorityNum, employeeCod) SELECT callId, priorityNum, employeeCod FROM calls";
    final String GETALL = "SELECT * FROM priorities";

    private Connection con;
    private PreparedStatement pstm;
    private Statement stm = null;
    private ResultSet rs = null;


    public MySQLPriorityDAO(Connection con) {
        this.con = con;
    }


    @Override
    public void insert(Priority o) throws DAOException {
        try{
           pstm = con.prepareStatement(INSERTFROM);
           /* \/ error under */
           pstm.setInt(1, o.getCallId());
           pstm.setInt(2, o.getPriorityNum());
           pstm.setInt(3, o.getEmployeeCod());

           if(pstm.executeUpdate() == 0 ){
              throw new DAOException("The update couldn't been saved");
           }  
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
         /* And it stops here */
            throw new DAOException("SQL Error", ex);
        } finally {
           if(pstm != null){
               try {
                   pstm.close();
               } catch (SQLException ex) {
                   throw new DAOException("Error to close connection", ex);
               }
           }
        }
    }
```

And the idea is to execute this function after that the user insert the data into another table from another form, that this function pick the insert data from another table and put in this other one (priorities):

```
private void btSubmitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        try {                                           
            Call call = new Call();
            Priority priority = new Priority();
            MySQLDaoManager man = new MySQLDaoManager("root", "", "localhost", "attendances", 3306);  

            try {
                call.setPriority(cbPriorityDetail.getSelectedItem().toString());
                call.setPriorityCod(Integer.parseInt(tfIdPriorityDetail.getText()));
                chamado.setEmployeeCod(Integer.parseInt(tfEmployeeCod.getText()));
                chamado.setInitialDate(new java.sql.Date(((java.util.Date)tfInitialDate.getValue()).getTime()));
                chamado.setInitialTime(Time.valueOf(tfInitialTime.getText()));
                chamado.setFinalTime(Time.valueOf(tfFinalTime.getText()));

              // this one is to insert all the data filled in the blank textfield as usual
                man.getCallDAO().insert(call);
              // here that i'm trying to pick the data from the call table to put in the priority table 
                man.getPriorityDAO().insert(priority);

                if(tfCallId.getText().length() != 0){
                     call.setCallId(Long.parseLong(tfCallId.getText()));
                     man.getCallDAO().update(call);
                }
                if(tfEmployeeCod.getText() != null && tfInitialDate.getValue() != null && tfInitialTime.getValue() != null && tfFinalTime.getValue() != null){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Data Inserted!", "Successful", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    btNewActionPerformed(evt);
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Please fill the fields again", "Not Successful", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    btNewActionPerformed(evt);
                }
/* IT IS RETURNING THIS BLOCK ABOVE SHOWING MySQL Error   */
            } catch (DAOException ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "MySQL Error", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Error to establish connection", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
}
```

The exception stack trace generated:

```
run:
br.com.jdbc.dao.DAOException: SQL Error
    at br.com.jdbc.victor.dao.daoentities.MySQLPriorityDAO.insert(MySQLPriorityDAO.java:58)
    at br.com.jdbc.victor.dao.daoentities.MySQLPriorityDAO.insert(MySQLPriorityDAO.java:28)
    at br.com.jdbc.victor.view.FormNewCall.btSubmitActionPerformed(FormNewCall.java:367)
    at br.com.jdbc.victor.view.FormNewCall.access$500(FormNewCall.java:22)
    at br.com.jdbc.victor.view.FormNewCall$6.actionPerformed(FormNewCall.java:146)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:184)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:229)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1084)
    at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1671)
    at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1623)
    at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1014)
    at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1005)
    at br.com.jdbc.victor.view.FormNewCall.lambda$main$0(FormNewCall.java:543)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:988)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:974)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.checkBounds(PreparedStatement.java:3813)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setInternal(PreparedStatement.java:3795)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setInternal(PreparedStatement.java:3840)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setInt(PreparedStatement.java:3784)
    at br.com.jdbc.victor.dao.entidadesdao.MySQLPriorityDAO.insert(MySQLPriorityDAO.java:50)
    ... 62 more
```

I did it at the cmd and it worked fine without error, here it returns that catch block with DAOException... am I supposed to put any result set there or change it to statement?

Comment: Make up your mind. Will the data used by that statement come from your Java code or from the `calls` table? Right now the SQL statement copies data from the `calls` table, and the SQL statement doesn't have any `?` parameter markers, which means that it cannot accept data from your Java code, but you still supply 3 values from Java, and that is what the error message says: You call `setInt(1, ...)` but there is no parameter marker for that.

Comment: that's it!! The idea is this one, catch all the data used from the `calls` table and fill the `priorities` table with these 3 fields... so, in this case i must to start the `statement` method, copy all the `calls` data one by one and after fill them one by one at the `priorities` table isn't it?!

Comment: What do you mean "one-by-one"? An INSERT-from-SELECT statement is a mass-copy. All records matching the `WHERE` clause of the select statement (you have none, so *all* records in `calls`) will be copied to the target table.

Comment: Your insert in `INSERTFROM` doesn't have any parameters, so of course you'll get an error saying _"java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)"_

Comment: As a side note: snippets are only for Javascript, HTML and CSS; don't use them for Java code.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing the WHERE condition in your select, that would specify from which exactly call you are copying the data:

Here's the modified code:

```
final String INSERTFROM = "INSERT INTO priorities " + 
                          "(callId, priorityNum, employeeCod) " + 
                          "SELECT callId, priorityNum, employeeCod " + 
                          "FROM calls WHERE callId=?"; // note WHERE here

@Override
public void insert(Priority o) throws DAOException {
    try{
       pstm = con.prepareStatement(INSERTFROM);
       /* \/ error under */
       pstm.setInt(1, o.getCallId());
       // no need in setting other values, since they are copied 
       // from the calls table

       if(pstm.executeUpdate() == 0 ){
          throw new DAOException("The update couldn't been saved");
       }  
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
     /* And it stops here */
        throw new DAOException("SQL Error", ex);
    } finally {
       if(pstm != null){
           try {
               pstm.close();
           } catch (SQLException ex) {
               throw new DAOException("Error to close connection", ex);
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey!! i did now in this way how you showed me, the code executes fine until the ´if(pstm.executeUpdate() == 0 ){' part, but it don't perform the update and throw the DAOException under it, and the SQLException after i don't know why... when i performed it in cmd it works fine!!

Comment: i think that it don't be catching the callId

Comment: Can you provide the stacktrace?

Comment: yes, it generated this stacktrace:
br.com.jdbc.dao.DAOException: The update couldn't been saved
 at br.com.jdbc.victor.dao.daoentities.MySQLPriorityDAO.insert(MySQLPriorityDAO.java:51)
 at br.com.jdbc.victor.dao.daoentities.MySQLPriorityDAO.insert(MySQLPriorityDAO.java:28)
 at br.com.jdbc.victor.view.FormNewCall.btSubmitActionPerformed(FormNewCall.java:368)
 at br.com.jdbc.victor.view.FormNewCall.access$500(FormNewCall.java:22)
        at br.com.jdbc.victor.view.FormNewCall$6.actionPerformed(FormNewCall.java:146)

Comment: while i was debugging the code, i watched that it isn't getting the `id` from the `calls` table, maybe because that the i can't able to catch all the data from this table

Comment: or i don't know if i'm supposed to do this function passing `(Call o)` as reference instead `(Priority o)`